# why the output of the expression --- 'a' and 'e' and 'i' and 'o' and 'u' in 'eiou' --- is true?

Tags: python

```
'a' and 'e' and 'i' and 'o' and 'u' in 'eiou'    
true
```

However,

```
'a' and 'e' and 'i' and 'o' and 'u' in 'aeio'   
false
```

what is the problem?

Comment: `('a' and 'e' and 'i' and 'o') and 'u' in 'eiou'` - that is how this line is interpreted

Comment: Welcome to SO! `'a' and 'e' and 'i' and 'o'` is always true. These test the truth value of string literals, i.e. whether they're empty strings or not. So the last comparison is all that matters, `'u' in 'aeio'` which is false and `'u' in 'eiou'` which is true

Comment: Because `and` is a binary logical operator that evaluates both sides and `'u' in 'aeio'` evaluates to false. I would suggest a basic Python book like Think Python writen by Allen B. Downey (for the most essential parts, it won't take more than 3 days even if you have no programming experience at all). Ideally, your code should read like english, but it is not english anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'a' and 'e' and 'i' and 'o' and 'u' in 'eiou'
```

is equivalent to

```
if ('a') and ('b') and ('i') and ('o') and ('u' in 'eiou')
```

in which all the first 4 expressions 'a', 'b', 'i' and 'o' evaluate to True.

The final expression ('u' in 'eiou') is True for the first statement, whereas 'u' in 'aeio' is False

Answer (score 0):

emm... It is the way python evaluates conditional expressions. This is how it works:

`'a' and 'e' and 'i' and 'o' and 'u' in 'eiou'`

`'a'` -> a non-empty string always evaluates to True, so we got True.

`and` -> if the expression before 'and' evaluates to True, evaluate the next expression.

`'e'` -> True

`and` -> continue evaluation

`'i'` -> True

`and` -> continue evaluation

`'o'` -> True

`and` -> continue evaluation

`'u' in 'eiou'` -> True

So you got True.

The next expression:

`'a' and 'e' and 'i' and 'o' and 'u' in 'aeio'`

`'a'` -> True

`and` -> continue evaluation

`'e'` -> True

and -> continue evaluation

`'i'` -> True

and -> continue evaluation

`'o'` -> True

and -> continue evaluation

`'u' in 'aeio'` -> False

so you got a False.

If what you want is to check if all letters are in the string, you either `'a' in 'aeio' and 'e' in 'aeio' and ...` or more efficiently: `if set('aeiou').issuperset(('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', ...))`.